# MySQL - Persistent Connections (or) sleeping connections

Tags: mysql, persistent

We have few IIS servers with ASP .NET based websites. They are connected to MySQL Database. For every 2 - 3 days the MySQL Database connection pool filling with sleeping connections and we have to manually close left connection which are with status as sleeping.

Is there any way i close those persisted connections of MySQL ?

Thank you.

Comment: For this you can decrease the value of `wait_timeout` in `MySQL`

Comment: is this require service restart or on the fly can we do it ?

Comment: You can set this with `SET GLOBAL wait_timeout = 30` without server restart , for permanent changes add it in my.cnf

Answer (score 1):

From  [**This link**](http://www.webmasterworld.com/php/3520191.htm) , The importance of Persistent connections is as

> Persistent connections are efficient because there is no overhead to
>   make a connection between PHP and MySQL, every time a PHP script is
>   executed. The main drawback however is that resources may be easily
>   wasted because MySQL keeps some data of that connection in its cache,
>   even when no PHP script is currently using the connection. A common
>   problem are result sets of large SELECT queries that may stay in
>   memory long after there usefulness in the PHP script that requested
>   the data has ended. These result sets are using available resources
>   and could be the source of the resource problem you currently see.
>
> The proper way to deal with this is carefully calling the
>   mysql_free_result() function whenever returned data from a SELECT
>   statement is no longer needed. This may free up enough resources for
>   your MySQL server to run smoothly again.

How to controll behaviour of persistent connections

> the behaviour of persistent connections can be tuned in
>   your PHP.INI file with the mysql.allow_persistent and
>   mysql.max_persistent settings.

Comment: Thank you for clear explanation but we are having ASP .NET sites & not PHP.